# Get if a user is authenticated on Firebase initializeApp

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I do:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

the first time after a refresh for some milliseconds currentUser is null. 
But later the currentUser value gets filled. Of course previously I authenticated without sign out.

How can I initializeApp and wait till I really know the user is loggedin or not? I mean `firebase.initializeApp` and `firebase.auth()` are not promises.
Is there any promise to know that the user is logged in or not? I could not find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now often use an `onAuthStateChanged()` handler to detect if the user is signed in.

```
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user == null) {
          // TODO: start sign-in flow
      }
      else {
          // TODO: start actual work
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: But the onAuthStateChanged is called even if the user was never loggedin?

Comment: Yes. It is called immediately with the initial/currently known state and then whenever the state changes. Try it!

Comment: This is how it's done.  `.onAuthStateChanged` "By using an observer, you ensure that the Auth object isn't in an intermediate state—such as initialization—when you get the current user." [Manage Users in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).  BTW - I have a [Web auth boilerplate on Github](https://github.com/rhroyston/firebase-auth).  Demo [here](https://rack.pub/firebase-auth).